# The past tense instead of the past perfect tense

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

I have seen a sentence, where, for my part, the past tense is used instead of the past perfect tense. Here is the the sentence:

"I am able to let go of who I thought I was supposed to be"

Must it not be "I am able to let go of who I thought I had been supposed to be"? Tell me please if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both tenses are valid there and can mean slightly different things in context, you are wrong to think it wrong.

> who you **were supposed to be**

refers to a belief held about your identity or a plan others had for your life.

> who you **had been supposed to be**

refers to a belief that had been held about your identity or a plan others had had for your life.

When you refer to something you are able to do now:

> I am able to let go {of something}

and the something is a notion about yourself held in the past:

> ...  who I **thought**

the content of that held notion could be something *concurrent* with the notion or something that *predated* the notion.

However, since you choose the verb **let go**, the thing must have existed at the time of the letting go in order for it to be let go of:

> I was able to reject the plans my family had for my career.

The past perfect doesn't quite fly:

> I was able to reject the plans my family had had for my career.

If the plans existed only prior to the rejection, they cannot really be rejected except in retrospect, which is really a moot issue.  Things would be different with **assess**:

> I was able to assess the plans my family had had for my career, and I came to understand that they had been correct in wanting me to become a lion tamer instead of a rock star. I regret that I fought their wishes and caused them to relent.

Answer (score 0):

The time we are refering to in the past is when the "I thought" happened.  If you use the past perfect tense it means that the "supposed to be" action was completed before the "I thought" action took place.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is no reason to cast *BE (supposed)* in the past perfect; the clause headed by this *BE* does not designate a state occurring before *THINK* but a state occurring simultaneous with *think*.

> PAST: I thought then that I **was** supposed to be person X.
>
> PRESENT: I can now let go of person X. I now think that I **am** supposed to be person Y.

There are contexts in which it would be meaningful to cast *THINK* in the past perfect:

> PAST: During my college years I **was able** to let go of the person I **had** previously **thought** that I was supposed to be.

But a past-perfect *BE supposed to be* would occur only if it designated a state which lay before some past *THINK*:

> When I arrived at college I thought that I had been supposed to be person X during my high school years. I was surprised to learn that in fact I had been supposed to be person Y.

That, however, is very difficult to square with the deontic sense of *suppose*, the person people or I myself had wanted me to be; it's more likely to represent the epistemic sense, the person people or I myself had thought I actually was.